# Pass hidden model data to the controller using ajax in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Once again stumped on a partial view issue using ajax to swap out partial views.

I have a partial view that is loaded onto a page when the page is loaded.  This partial view has a button on it that when clicked, will replace that partial view with another partial view.  Previously I was accomplishing this with `@Ajax.ActionLink` and passing in the page's Model as a parameter to be passed to the controller.  This was working correctly.

However, the next step was to fill in a form on the new partial view and submit it which would return another partial view.  I asked how to do that on here and got it to work using jquery event delegation.

Now I'm trying to replace the `@Ajax.ActionLink` with a `$.ajax` function and am running into an issue with my js script where the model data already in the view or partial view is not being passed to the controller by the js.

Here's what I mean:

I have a page called **ReviewPage** that on load, will call an action that returns a partial view.  This partial view is determined based on a value from the page's model that is passed to the controller.  More often than not, the view returned is **_NoNotes**:

```
@model GuestPointerAppV4.Models.ViewModels.NotesOnCompanyViewModel

<div id="no_company_notes">
    <h4>Notes on Company</h4>

    <div class="row col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
        <div class="text-center">
            @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.RequestId)
            <div class="primary-action-bttn-border">
                <div class="primary-action-bttn-bkg">
                    <button data-gp-ajax="true" data-gp-target="#no_company_notes" value="Save" action="@Url.Action("_CompanyNotesEditGet", "NewSignUpRequestReview")" method="get" class="btn btn-default primary-action-bttn">
                        Add Note
                    </button>
                    @*@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Note", "_CompanyNotesEditGet", Model, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "company_notes", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default primary-action-bttn" })*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center padding-25-top">
        <p>There are no notes for this company.  Do you want to add some?</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

*You'll notice the commented out ajax action link in the code above.  This was how I was previously able to get the model passed to the controller.*

When the button is clicked on this partial view, the following js responds:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[data-gp-ajax="true"]', function () {

    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done (function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-gp-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

I want to reuse this js as much as possible so I utilize custom data- attributes to help call the right function (data-gp-ajax="true") and tell the script where to return the results (data-gp-target="#targetid").

The problem is that in debugging this, I found that while `Model.RequestId` is not 0 on the page, this value is not getting picked up by the js and passed to the controller.  So, when my controller looks for the data it doesn't find it and returns a null or 0 depending on the type of data I'm trying to pass.

I did a bit of research and tried to encode the Model in the partial view itself using the following at the top of the partial view's code just after the model typing:

```
@{ 
    var val = Json.Encode(Model);
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model1 = @Html.Raw(val)
</script>
```

Then, in my js function, I tried passing model1 to the controller by using it like so:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[data-gp-ajax="true"]', function () {

    var $form = $(this);

    var $model = $(model1);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $model.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done (function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-gp-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

I also tried `data: $model` and `data: $model.first()` but no such luck.  I managed to debug and see the data I was expecting to see in the js on the $model variable so I know it's getting in there but it isn't getting passed to my controller when it's called.

Really what I'm looking for is a clean and reliable way way to pass the Model for the page into the JavaScript and have it pass it along to the Controller to execute some action on before a partial view is returned to replace the original partial view.

Thoughts?

**Update**

Here is an example of the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _CompanyNotesEditGet(NotesOnCompanyViewModel notesOnCompanyViewModel)
{
  //Some actions are taken on the model passed in and then repopulated to notesOnCompanyViewModel

    return PartialView("~/Views/NotesOnCompany/_CompanyNotesEdit.cshtml", notesOnCompanyViewModel);
}
```

However, when I debug and the action is called by $.ajax, the notesOnCompanyViewModel is blank.  Even when I can see there is data that should be getting passed by the js function.

Comment: Its not clear what your trying to the controller (you have not shown your controller methods) but you should only passing the ID of the model,not the whole model itself. And `model1` is already your model, so it would just be `data: model1` any way if you did want to pass the original model back to the controller (but that would be crazy)

Comment: And you really over complicating it with all those `data-*` attributes and adding invalid attributes (`action` and `method`) in your `<button>`

Comment: It might be over complicating it to have `data-*` attributes in the view but it makes the js a lot more adaptable (if i can get it working...).

Comment: No it will not. But you should not be passing the whole model back to a GET method (if the model contains any properties that are complex objects then it will fail anyway, and you risk exceed the query string limit and throwing an exception). Just pass back the ID of the model and get the data object again. And you do not need your `@Html.HiddenFor()`.

Comment: And its unclear why you replacing everything. From your previous question, it looks like what you really want is a pop-up modal form to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to send the unique Id. for that, you can simply override the button click event and make an ajax call with the Id in the request url. If you would like to take advantage of the Url helper method to generate the correct relative path to the action method, you can do that and set the result of that to html5 data attribute on the button.

```
<button id="addNote" 
    data-url="@Url.Action("_CompanyNotesEditGet", "NewSignUpRequestReview",
                                                           new { id=Model.RequestId})" >
                    Add Note
</button>
```

Assuming your `_CompanyNotesEditGet` action method accepts this `Id` and return the value as needed

```
public ActionResult _CompanyNotesEditGet(int id)
{
   var vm= new NotesOnCompanyViewModel { RequestId=id };
   //load other properties of vm as needed.
   return PartialView(""~/Views/NotesOnCompany/_CompanyNotesEdit.cshtml",vm);
}
```

And the script to ajaxify the click event. You can use the `load` method to make the ajax call and update the DOM element.

```
$(function(){

   $(document).on("click","#addNote",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var url=$(this).data("url");
      $("#no_company_notes").load(url);
   });

});
```

If you are editing a note, Inside your action method, you can read your note entity from the db using the Id passed in.

This should work assuming you have no script errors in the page.

Comment: OP is actually calling `.serialize()` on the variable `$model` (which already the serialized model) - but that also makes no sense :)

Comment: I see. I thought he was calling on `$form` !